# System of equations: formula of solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

I've got the following system:
$$ Q \left( \matrix{y\\x} \right) = \left( \matrix{b\\f} \right)$$

where $$Q = \left( \matrix{A \ B\\B^T \ C} \right) \in \mathbb R^{(n+m) \times (n+m)}$$ and
$$ A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$$ regular,
$$ B\in \mathbb R^{n \times m}, C \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}, b \in \mathbb R^{n}, f \in \mathbb R^{m}, x \in \mathbb R^{m}, y\in \mathbb R^{n}$$

What's a correct formula for the solution for y in dependance of $$ A^{-1}, B, b, x$$?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Use **\left($\ldots$\right)** to adjust the size of your brackets.

Comment: Done, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Q(\matrix{y\\x}) = (\matrix{b\\f}) \iff b=Ay+Bx$ and $f=B^Ty+Cx$.

From $ b=Ay+Bx $ we get $y=A^{-1}(b-Bx)$.

Comment: Use **\left($\ldots$\right)** to adjust the size of your brackets.

Comment: Hi Fred! Thank you very much, you helped me a lot! Now if I've got the system of equation B^T y + Cx = f and if I use our y, we get: B^T (A^(-1)(b-Bx))+Cx = f. Let A be symmetric positive definite and C symmetric negative definite ==> Q is regular. Why is this? Just because of the fact that A^(-1) is also symmetric positive definite and B^T y is diagonal?